# Limitations of Marc-32 machine numbers

Tags: numerical-methods, real-numbers

I am in doubt whether I understand Marc-32 machine numbers limitations correctly, however, before I try to explain my questions, I will just shortly explain how one find Marc-32 numbers (to ensure that I have understood that correctly).

**How I understand Marc-32 numbers:**

If we have the decimal number $0.25$ as a simple example, the Marc-32 number is found step by step:

1. Find binary number: $(0.25)_{10}=({0.01})_{\text{b}}$
2. Multiply so it becomes on the form $1.0...$: $1.0\times 2^{-2}$, as we know the first number is 1, we can store and extra bit by writing on the form 1.0 instead of 0.1.
3. Add 127 to the exponent in 2, as we use excess representation: $0.1\times 2^{-2+127}$
4. Find binary number of exponent: $0.1\times 2^{1111101}$
5. We write the marc number with 0 in front, as the number is positive, then put the exponent, put the fraction from (2) that 0 (from the 1.0) and fill the last 22 numbers, after the $0$ from the fraction, with 0: $0111110100000000000000000000000$

**Questoins regarding its limitations:**

If this understanding of how to make Marc-32 numbers is correct, then I'm in doubt about the following observations about Marc-32 limitations:

- Infinite binary numbers cannot be Marc-32, as the mantissa only can hold a fraction where, when the fraction is on binary form, there can as maximum be a 22 zeros, and then a 1 (when we say there is 24 bits with having removed the first 1, as we just know is there) - elsewwise you will need extra bits. **Is that correct?**
- My professor says, that we reserve the exponent in step 2, so it isn't 0 or 255, as we have $(11111111)_{\text{b}}=256$ combinations, which is equal to the span from 0 to 255 in decimal numbers, where we don't want extremes. We use excess representation, so we add 127 to the exponent, e, is equal to the original exponent $m+127$. We have $e=m+127$ and $0<e<255$, so $-126\leq m\leq 127$ which means we have that a number we want to write as a Marc-32 machine number, has to be in $[2^{-126},2^{127}]$. **Is that correct?**

Comment: Do not assume that we ever heard of "Marc-32 machines".

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917730/machine-numbers-in-a-32-bits-binary-digits-computer

Comment: @YvesDaoust oh I see:
Marc-32 means we have 32 bits, which consists of a sign bit, 8 bit exponent and 24 bit mantissa. We have 24 bits in the mantissa, as Marc-32 is binary, and we know the first one is 1. Please see slide 31 on https://relate.cs.illinois.edu/course/cs357-sp16/file-version/0ef8987af6e7a06f431ebfc0dbd9872e8ed7a5f3/media/lecture03.pdf :)

Comment: @RobArthan - yeah, you are right - however, my question is more general regarding the limitations :)

Comment: @Frederik: there is a preference for MSE questions to be self-contained rather than rely on links to external websites for background. I suggest you cite the MSE link I gave in your question for the definitions.

Comment: Given all that, the quick answer is that both your observations are correct. I made a start on an more complete answer, but ran out of time. I can pick it up another day if you need more assistance.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you for the help - I needed som reassurance that my understanding is correct.